# How to stop telegram bot running when i stop running python script?

Tags: python, telegram

this is my first time using python to control telegram bot. I run this code below and would like to the bot to stop running. Could someone teach me how to make the telegram bot stop?

```
import time
import random
import datetime
import telepot
from telepot.loop import MessageLoop

def bot_test(msg):
    chat_id = msg['chat']['id']
    command = msg['text']
    
    
    print('Got command:',command) #text from telegram
    
    
    if command == '/roll':
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, random.randint(1, 2))
    elif command == '/time':
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, str(datetime.datetime.now()))
        
bot = telepot.Bot('bot token') 
MessageLoop(bot, bot_test).run_as_thread()
print ('I am listening ...')

while 1:
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Just remove the while loop

Answer (score 1):

The `while` loop never terminates as it's always true and is without any `break` statements. You could change it to like this:

```
while 1:
    time.sleep(10)
    break
```

**Edit:**

You also can change `while` loop to this:

```
while time.sleep(10):
    break
```

Now it terminates the loop after 10 seconds, and by this way you can make your code shorter instead of writing `while 1`.